# Is there a way to make "onkeydown" return slower

Tags: javascript

I want to increment an integer by holding down the right arrow key.  The function i made works, but it returns too fast.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                if (e.keyCode == '39') {

                        var steps = localStorage.getItem("steps");
                        if (+steps < 9) {
                            if (+steps === +steps) {
                                localStorage.setItem("steps", +steps + +1)
                            }
                        } else {
                            localStorage.setItem("steps", +steps - +10);
                        }
                        var sss = localStorage.getItem("steps");

                        unicorn.className = "unicorn_" + sss + "";

                        return false;
                }
            }
```

The code above is where i'm at now.  I am using localStorage to check the stored integer, and incrementing if it matches.  Once the integer gets to 9, it substracts back to 0.

can anyone see what i'm doing wrong, or not doing right?

Comment: setTimeout( function() {    //code that you want delayed goes here       },500);

Comment: hmmm, i've used a timeout earlier, but only a 100, not 500.  I'll try now

Comment: I recommend [Lodash's `_.throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) to avoid reinventing the wheels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to execute `too fast` then consider placing it in a `setTimeout`

```
var notTooFast = false;
var timeout   = 1000; // change it whatever you want to be

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '39') {

    if (!notTooFast)
    {
      var steps = localStorage.getItem("steps");
      if (+steps < 9) {
          if (+steps === +steps) {
              localStorage.setItem("steps", +steps + +1)
          }
      } else {
          localStorage.setItem("steps", +steps - +10);
      }
      var sss = localStorage.getItem("steps");

      unicorn.className = "unicorn_" + sss + "";

      notTooFast = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
          notTooFast = false;
      }, timeout);

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that did it, and thanks for that answer, i didn't know i could use the timeout with booleans that way.  You done learnt me today.

Answer (score 2):

You can also manually keep track of the time using a closure:

```
document.onkeydown = (function () {

    var T0 = Date.now();

    return function (event) {
        if (Date.now() - T0 > 500) {
            console.log("doing my thing over here", Math.random());
            T0 = Date.now();
        }
    }
})();
```